# Cmake: How to hold off finding libraries?

Tags: bash, build, cmake

I have a Cmake project where I use static libraries from another project (which uses its own unique build system).

I have a bash script set up which compiles the libraries.

The problem arises when a new user checkouts both project. The new user cannot do cmake until the libaries are properly compiled in the other project, and the cmake command find_libarary cant find them.

I made the bash script part of cmake by using the command add_custom_target. But the issue is that it only execute if you do a "make".

Is there a way I can make CMake execute a command while its generating a build system. Or a better way would be to have it ignore the find command until the actual make?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not LINK_DIRECTORIES(xxx) to the library folder and don't use find_library at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, [execute_process()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) function.